# in java what is the difference between adding each element to a list versus just assigning a list is to another

Tags: java

could someone please tell me the difference between adding each element to a list versus just assigning a list is to another;

// this constructor doesn't pass some tests

```
public Assembler(List<Fragment> fragments) {
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
```

// whereas this constructor passes all of them

```
public Assembler(List<Fragment> fragments) {
    for(int i = 0; i<fragments.size(); i++){
           this.fragments.add(fragments.get(i));
       }

}
```

Comment: can you share the test cases ?

Comment: If you want to ignore some values or if you have some condition then you can check while adding them to the list. Which isn't possible when you copy the object directly.

Comment: In the first case, there is 1 object, with 2 different references pointing to it. In the second case, you have 2 objects and one reference pointing to each of them.

Comment: If someone passes a list into your constructor, and then subsequently alters the list, do you want your class instance to be holding the original contents or the updated contents?

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple method that shows you the difference.  In the first case both `List` reference the same object, so modifying one will modify both.  In the second version they will be separate so modifying one will not modify the other.

```
     List<String> frag1 = new ArrayList<>();
     List<String> frag2 = new ArrayList<>();
     List<String> frag3 = new ArrayList<>();

     frag1.add("I was added to frag1");
     frag1.add("I also was added to frag1");


     frag2 = frag1;

     for (String s : frag1)
     {
     frag3.add(s);
     }

     frag2.add("I was added to frag2");
     frag3.add("I was added to frag3");

     System.out.println("Frag1: " + frag1.toString());
     System.out.println("Frag2: " + frag2.toString());
     System.out.println("Frag3: " + frag3.toString());
```

This will output:

```
Frag1: [I was added to frag1, I also was added to frag1, I was added to frag2]
Frag2: [I was added to frag1, I also was added to frag1, I was added to frag2]
Frag3: [I was added to frag1, I also was added to frag1, I was added to frag3]
```

As you can see, the original `List` was changed when `Frag2` added a value to it, and `Frag1` and `Frag2` are both equal.  However, adding a `String` to `Frag3` that used the second way of constructing it did not affect the original value of `Frag1` and was different from both `Frag2` and `Frag1` now.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example:

```
public Assembler(List<Fragment> fragments) {
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
```

In the former example, you're overwriting the list. Any elements that *used* to be in `this.fragments` are now no longer in `this.fragments` - rather, `this.fragments` is now pointing to a completely new list.

Whether or not this *matters* depends on how `this.fragments` was declared initially. It could be that it was declared in such a way that it already contained some variables:

```
private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(Arrays.asList(fragment1, fragment2, fragment3));
```

in which case, all of those would be overwritten. But this is unusual behavior for an instance variable.

Another, more likely, reason it might fail the test would be due to references - there might be a test somewhere that does something like this:

```
Assembler a = new Assembler(fragments);
assertFalse(fragments == a.fragments);
```

in which case, it'd be explicitly checking that you didn't just copy the list over by assessing whether or not the same reference is being invoked.

Similarly, if you did the assignment thing, it could lead to unintended behavior, such as adding an item to `fragments` and having it show up in `a.fragments` - which is also probably not wanted.

---

In the latter example, you're adding to the list instead:

```
public Assembler(List<Fragment> fragments) {
    for(int i = 0; i<fragments.size(); i++){
           this.fragments.add(fragments.get(i));
       }

}
```

This preserves the references to each individual element, but without reassigning `this.fragments` - so that, even afterwards, `fragments` and `this.fragments` refer to different objects, and thus modifying one will not modify the other.

There's a more concise way to do this, though, than looping through with a `for` loop:

```
public Assembler(List<Fragment> fragments) {
    this.fragments.addAll(fragments);
}
```